# Image and Kernel of a Projection of One Line onto Another

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

The question is: Let T be the projection along a line L1 onto a line L2. Describe the the image and the kernel of T geometrically.

I understand that the image should be the Projection of L1 onto L2. As this is a map to L2, L2 is the image. But why is L1 the kernel?

If we were working with two lines, L1 being X and L2 being L in the image below, shouldn't the kernel of the projection of L1 onto L2 be X_perp not L1?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You’re thinking of *orthogonal* projection onto $L_2$, but that’s not what you’ve been given. The projection onto $L_2$ is *along* $L_1$, that is, to find the image of a point you draw a line parallel to $L_1$ through that point and find its intersection with $L_2$.